# What does the syntax [] mean in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shader, pyopengl

I'm learning how to use shader in pyopengl through a sample project on GitHubGist. I came across "[]" syntax and I don't know what it means in this case.

I only know one use of "[]" which is indexing an array.

```py
    def initShader(self, vertex_shader_source, fragment_shader_source):
        # create program
        self.program=glCreateProgram()
        print('create program')
        printOpenGLError()

        # vertex shader
        print('compile vertex shader...')
        self.vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        glShaderSource(self.vs, [vertex_shader_source])
        glCompileShader(self.vs)
        glAttachShader(self.program, self.vs)
        printOpenGLError()
```

I don't understand the "[]" syntax used in glShaderSource()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `glShaderSource` accepts a list of code snippets.
See PyOpenGL documentation of [`glShaderSource`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glShaderSource.html):

> ```
> glShaderSource( GLhandle(shaderObj),[bytes(string),...]) -> None
> ```

`[vertex_shader_source]` is the list of strings, where each string contains glsl source code (`[]` generates a [`List`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)).
In this case the list contains only one element.
The elements of the list are concatenated and compiled.

See also the C specification of [`glShaderSource`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glShaderSource.xhtml)